# Recording/ monitoring equipment for band

Tags: audio-recording

In my band, we want to upgrade our gear for recording and monitoring and have some kind of studio environment in our band room.

Unfortunately, I don't know the possibilities of all those different kinds of gear and don't know what I would need exactly to fulfill our requirements.

What we want is to have monitoring via headphones in our band room and also possibilities to record our songs properly, ideally with multiple tracks.

Our first plan was to simply buy an analog mixer with 4 Aux tracks. That way, each of us (we are four people in the band) could get a separate mix into their headphones (correct me if I'm wrong) and we could record, but only with one track (or two at max)

So, we would need an interface with enough tracks (e.g. something like that)
With that we could route the output of the tracks from the mixer into the interface and then in our DAW, am I right?

Is there another possibility for our requirements? Another solution would be a digital mixer, but they are quite pricey =)

What do you think would be necessary?

Regarding the price, for the whole solution (headphones and individual headphone amps or something alike not included) for 500 or 600 bucks would be nice, 1000 as absolute maximum.

Comment: For recording, you shouldn't output the single channel of all instruments from the mixer to the interface. You should be directly inputting all instruments to the interface. So if I'm understanding your situation correctly, it wouldn't be possible if you follow this rule.